# JSF standard converters

Tags: jsf

I have a question regarding JSF conversion. I have an input text define like this:

```
<p:inputText size="15" maxlength="11" value="#{user.SSN}"/>
```

backing bean:

```
private Integer SSN;
```

From this site:
http://laliluna.com/articles/posts/javaserver-faces-converter-tutorial.html

I understand that JSF has built in converters for Integers.

"If you don’t specify a converter, JSF will pick one for you. The framework has standard converters for all of the basic types: Long, Byte, Integer, Short, Character, Double,
Float, BigDecimal, BigInteger and Boolean.. For example, if your component is associated with a property of type boolean, JSF will choose the Boolean converter. Primitive types are automatically converted to their object counterparts."

however when I execute the above code, I got this error:

```
j_idt78: '99999999999' must be a number consisting of one or more digits.
```

What is wrong with my understanding this concept? Why doesn't JSF uses its standard converters in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not completely sure but I am positive that the number 99999999999 is far too large to be stored as an Integer, so instead it defaults to treat it like a String.

If you change the field SSN to a `Long` or `BigInteger` then it will probably work correctly.  Optionally you can explicitly specify a number converter for this field directly by adding the following Facelets tag inside of the Primefaces tag `<f:convertNumber>`

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/convertNumber.html

Comment: Indeed, the maximum value of an `Integer` can by the way be determined by `Integer.MAX_VALUE` which is `2147483647`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I solved my problem by setting SSN as String but I am still curious about this case. Do you think the problem occurred because of the size of the input value? I've heard that convertNumber is a little bit problematic. If I choose convertNumber, I should also define my SSN as Number, right?

Comment: @lamostreta I am actually not sure if it will be able to convert it to the super type Number, but try it out and see if it works.  How you decide to do this is your design choice.  Personally I choose to store all ManagedBean state data as String or a data object that I wrote a custom converter for.  I usually do all String to Primitive data type conversion in the ManagedBean before calling my business logic layer.